# IdentityServer3 - Incremental Authorization (leastprivilege)

Tags: oauth, authorization, identityserver3

I'm looking to have the client with an access token (reference token) with scope access to call API 1, API 1 will call API 2, API 2 will call Id3 to add the scope (if client is allow) to the access token.

If this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, all you need is an endpoint on your ID3 project that adds/writes that scope to the same repository/datastore that your `IScopeStore` uses.